# Page Navigation in Windows phone 7 Web App

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, web-applications, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing an web app for Windows Phone 7 using jquery mobile.

I want to navigate to a page say index.html to sample.html.

```
function sample() 
{
     window.location.href = "Sample.html";
     navigator.notification.alert("Navigated);             
}
```

It works fine.

But when a querystring is added with "sample.html?id=123123"

```
 function sample() 
    {
         window.location.href = "Sample.html?id=123123";
         navigator.notification.alert("Navigated");             
    }
```

This navigation does not work.

Can anyone please guide.Anyother navigation method along with querystring is also welcome.

Comment: Does not work meaning it doesn't navigate, or the id property is undefined?

Comment: @willmel  The page is not naivgating to the sample page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can not use a querystring in web application using phonegap for windows phone 7.
Instead we can use `Sample.html#12312`

Answer (score 0):

What is txt? It looks like it might be throwing an exception when you try to access txt.value,  because txt is null. I assume it is a textbox on the page, so you'd have to access it like `$("input#txt").val();` instead

Comment: Actually txt is just for an example.We can just hardcode querystring 'Sample.html?id=123123'

Answer (score 0):

In a PhoneGap Windows Phone application it should be like:

```
document.location = "Sample.html#id=123123";
```

Or:

```
window.location.href = "Sample.html#id=123123";
```